# How can I get/create camera calibration files for jsartoolkit?

Tags: nft, artoolkit, jsartoolkit

I need camera_para.dat files for newer devices with wide-angle lenses for an NFT project I'm working on.  The default calibration works well across most older devices, but I'm finding that with newer phones it simply won't track.  There doesn't appear to be any central repository of calibration files so we need to create our own. As the default calibration seems quite forgiving I'm hoping that I will only need a few to cover all devices.

How can I calibrate cameras across iOS and Android devices, or is there somewhere I can find the calibration data?

Answer (score 0):

## Calib_camera app

You should use create a custom calibration file for your webcam, as described in this [camera calibration guide](https://kalwalt.github.io/artoolkit-docs/2_Configuration/config_camera_calibration.html) -> Markdown file [here](https://github.com/kalwalt/artoolkit-docs/blob/master/2_Configuration/config_camera_calibration.md) The problem is that app is very old and you can find the source code (calib_camera.cpp) in an old [ARToolkit5 version](https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5/blob/6323b0ca3fecb65184f3de854de4b85747894883/util/calib_camera/calib_camera.cpp) If you look into the code you can see that use an old OpenCV version, for example it use `IplImage` and `CvPoint2D32f` you need to change these and other old OpenCV methods. I think you could do with either Artoolkit5 or ArtoolkitX, because the code base are basically the same.
From a web point o view this could be done also with Emscripten and develop a broswer app for it, maybe i could do inside our [WebARKit](https://github.com/webarkit) organization, but i can't say when...

### Calibaration camera with artoolkitx-calibration

To add more: there is also this project [artoolkitx-calibration](https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkitx-calibration)
that is most updated and tailored for Mobile devices.